# How to disable validation by default for a model with Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, sequelize.js

I'm trying to disable validations by default for a model with Sequelize.
Currently, I'm always creating/updating my object with:

```
Model.create({attrs}, {validate: false})
```

I tried in the model file :

```
sequelize.define('Model', {attrs}, {validate: false})
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Can I set validate to false somewhere in the model definition in order to avoid writing validate: false in each of my create/update function?
Thanks.